# C# Unity: Unable to stop Coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Once I call this coroutine I am unable to stop it again and it will just go on forever. I have already tried to call it with a string etc...

this block is in a method that is being called in the update method could that have anything to do with it???

This is my code:

```
 if (currentAmmo < 2 && isColorFading == false) {

        StartCoroutine (ColourPulse (ammoCounter, initialColor, 2));
        isColorFading = true;

    } else if (currentAmmo >= 2 && isColorFading == true) {

        StopCoroutine (ColourPulse (ammoCounter, initialColor, 2)); 
        ammoCounter.color = initialColor;
        isColorFading = false;
    }
```

Comment: what happens if `currentAmmo` equals to 2? Or what happens if `currentAmmo` is never grater than 2 while `isColorFading` is `true`

Comment: oops that was a mistake..let me edit...sry

Comment: you have to debug and see. Maybe you need to use `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: what would i write into debug???

Comment: Put `Debug.Log` in each if statement with different message to see what's going on in your code. That's what he meant.

Comment: i just did it and both statements happen at the right time its just the stopcoroutine thats not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is simple. In few words, you must keep a reference of your coroutine in order to stop it :

```
private IEnumerator myCoroutine ;

// [...]

if (currentAmmo < 2 && isColorFading == false) {

    myCoroutine = ColourPulse (ammoCounter, initialColor, 2) ;
    StartCoroutine ( myCoroutine ) ;
    isColorFading = true;

} else if (currentAmmo >= 2 && isColorFading == true) {

    StopCoroutine (myCoroutine); 
    ammoCounter.color = initialColor;
    isColorFading = false;
}
```

Comment: For your information, Stack Overflow has a Documentation category with a lot of examples about various subjects including Unity, check it out ! ;) http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/unity3d/topics

Answer (score 0):

You can also try simple

```
Coroutine myCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ColourPulse (ammoCounter, initialColor, 2);
StopCoroutine(myCorutine);
```

because StartCoroutine is a method that returns Coroutine type object that it started.